# Regarding inner classes private member variable access

Tags: java, private-members

Say there is an class named `MyOuter` which consists of a simple inner class named `MyInner`.  In trying to learn how inner classes work, I'm trying to understand whether an outer class private member variable is accessible from the inner class itself or not.

```
class MyOuter {
  private int x = 7;
  // inner class definition
  class MyInner {
    public void seeOuter() {
      System.out.println("Outer x is " + x);
    }
  } // close inner class definition
} // close outer class
```

As per my analysis, the preceding code is perfectly legal. Notice that the inner class is indeed accessing a private member of the outer class. That's fine, because the inner
class is also a member of the outer class. So just as any member of the outer class
(say, an instance method) can access any other member of the outer class, private
or not, the inner class (also a member) can do the same.

Please advise whether my reason was correct or not.

Comment: Correct, but you can ask your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

an inner class is a member of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields. for more information, please see [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Isn't it the same OP also mentioned.... "the inner class is also a member of the outer class. So just as any member of the outer class (say, an instance method) can access any other member of the outer class, private or not, the inner class—also a member—can do the same"

Comment: @Jayamohan, Right, this was just me saying **yes, he's right**. And then I provided some reference material. I don't see what the problem is here? Also, does the down-voter care to explain?

Comment: yeah, If "YES" is included in the reply It would have been great, thats why commented.

Comment: The access, strictly speaking, is not direct. At least, not unless a JIT compiler optimizes it. Instead, package-private accessors are synthesized in the enclosing class at compile time. The inner class uses these accessors, rather than directly accessing the fields.